# Assign Static IP to the Raspberry Pi using 'nmcli' or any other tool on Raspbian Jessie-lite

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, debian-jessie, networkmanager

I'm using Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian Jessie-lite. I want to assign Static IP to the Raspberry Pi using 'nmcli' or any other tool.

Raspbian Jessie-lite comes with wpa_supplicant and other networking tools. I have already used them but the problem is I have to restart the device when I connect to new Wi-Fi network or change assign static IP.

As a solution to the problem I used network-manager nmcli(0.9, higher versions are not available for jessie). But I cannot find a way to assign static ip details for Wi-Fi.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. It's all about computer hardware, and software. Not for Raspberry. You can ask here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hello @CaldeiraG I understand this, but Raspberry pi is just for specifying the hardware I'm using, majorly it's about Debian - Jessie and Network-Manager tool.